# In Visual Studio Code C# how do I disable the behavior where it creates a document block whenever /// is typed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

When coding in C#, whenever I type

```
  ///
```

VS Code turns it into

```
  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
```

And then when I hit enter it keeps adding more lines:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  ///
```

How do I disable this behavior?

I have tried looking in the C# and Editor settings, but could not find anything.

Comment: simply type `CTRL+Z`  after that happens.... 

Answer (score 1):

These behaviors are part of the "Format On Type" feature, which you can disable by going to:

- Settings (Ctrl+,)
- User
- Text Editor
- Formatting
- Format On Type

and making sure the box is unchecked, or alternatively, making sure the `editor.formatOnType` option is `false` in `settings.json`.

You may need to restart Code for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Turning off Format On Type did stop this behavior, however I *do* want to have Format On Type enabled, so it auto formats all my other code. I just want to disable the behavior of it creating those additional lines when typing /// - which isn't actually 'formatting' my code but rather it creating extra code automatically. Hopefully there is a way to disable this or change the behavior. Eg. what if some users or organizations have a different standard format for their documentation comments?

Comment: These documentation comments, so with the `<summary>` tags, are part of the C# spec - they're the only format that has special support in the C# compiler and associated tooling like Visual Studio and Code. If an organisation wants to use C#, wants to use triple-slash documentation comments in C#, but does not want to use the syntax in the standard, I suppose they're free to do so, but they'll have to change or reinvent that tooling.